# How did 'He who remains' manage to live for so long?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

As we know, humans have a limited lifetime but as described in the Loki TV series, 'He who Remains' was managing the various timelines through TVA and he mentioned that he was living at the end of time for million years.

> I’ve lived a million lifetimes
>
> <sub>[Loki – S01E06 – For All Time. Always
> [Transcript]](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2021/07/14/loki-s01e06-for-all-time-always-transcript/)</sub>

How did he manage to not get old? Has he stopped time for himself to remain young forever?

Comment: He has access to technology from across the universe and along the entire timeline, so halting aging is probably trivially easy.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding was he was observing events from 'outside' of any specific timeline. That was why you could see all the new timelines splitting off outside his fortress.

Because of this time didn't pass for him.

EDIT:  With hindsight, this doesn't actually work, as Loki and Sylvie's timeline continued while in the fortress.